# C# AmazonDeviceFarmClient ListDevicesAsync not returning full list of devices

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

We use the `AmazonDeviceFarmClient.ListDevicesAsync` call with a very simple `ListDevicesRequest` in order to get a list of all devices available in Device Farms in a C# platform.

An example of our code:

```
var cfg = new AmazonDeviceFarmConfig
{
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2
};

using (var client = new AmazonDeviceFarmClient(new BasicAWSCredentials([DeviceFarmAccessKey], [DeviceFarmSecretKey]), cfg))
{
    var arn = GetProjectArn();

    var response = client.ListDevicesAsync(new ListDevicesRequest
    {
        Arn = arn
    }).Result;
}
```

On Powershell/python, using the `aws devicefarm list-devices` command, a comprehensive list of all possible devices is returned.

Using our C# code we get a truncated list, missing several devices that we need, despite there being no filters. We have tried various things including changing the permissions of the API user, and changing the region with no luck.

It looks increasingly like our best course of action will be to run a powershell script within our C# environment, rather than using the C# Device Farm API, whose list devices command appears to be not working.

Given that we are waiting for a result using the `Result` keyword, I would not expect this to be an async issue.

Comment: `ListDevicesRequest` has a tempting `NextToken` property which implies that this is one of many HTTP APIs designed in such a way as to only enumerate as much as they please (in the name of responsiveness and saving resources), requiring you to explicitly continue if you need more. Try calling again with that token set to see if you get more (and then presumably you'd need to loop that until it doesn't return anything anymore).

Comment: That's the fix. I got a bit confused because it was sending an uneven number of results down (something like 234). Using the next token property gave us the remaining 17 or so devices. Thank you so much for pointing this out as I'd gotten myself into a bit of a rabbit hole!

Comment: The number may be limited not by number of rows (which would be obvious) but by amount of data sent in bytes or time taken to produce the results or even something sharded across servers. There's probably something more or less reasonable going on, but you don't get to see it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jeroen Mostert, we missed out on the NextToken property. It was sending an incomplete list down (an uneven number, like 236, which made us think that it wasn't a pagination type issue), and using NextToken in a repeat call to the same method gave us the few remaining results.

Thank you for your prompt response!